# How can a vampire navigates a mirror maze?

Tags: fantasy-races, tactics, strategy, dungeons

Imagine a huge maze consists of mirrors on all sides, these are tempered glass coated with very reflective finishes. The ceiling is also made of tempered glass but it allows a certain wavelength of sunlight that do not cause discomfort to the vampire. If the vampire couldn't see it's reflection and shadow then how does it escape the mirror maze? All glass panels and ceiling are not glued or bolted together meaning you can easily create a cascading dominos effect with a single push on one of the mirror. I am looking for a proven strategy or methodology to allow the vampire to escape in the shortest time possible without too many unnecessary detours.

Comment: If the panels aren’t bolted together then the strategy is the same for a vampire as for anyone else. Pick a direction and walk in a straight line, pushing aside panels that are in your way.

Comment: I'm not sure how this differs for vampires (ones without reflection) compared to any other person (who has a reflection). In both cases, the issue is the extra confusion from there being mirrors. A vampire won't see themselves but would still see the reflections of everything else. While any other person will also see themselves. But it seems like an insignificant difference. In reality, a maze is a maze. The mirror maze just has, well, mirrors for walls. It's fundamentally not different to a hedge or concrete or any other maze.

Comment: Sorry I thought vampire is afraid of sunlight, can be crushed by glass panel, without reflection and shadow would probably make it hard to distinguish an opening or mirror. My bad this is on me

Comment: I would look into how a blind person would navigate a maze. There might be a solution in that.

Answer (score 3):

Vampires are traditionally not reflected into mirrors, but they are also not harmed by them.

So the exit strategy is rather straightforward, for a standard maze: they put their right hand on the wall and keep walking while never losing contact with the wall. Sooner or later they will reach the exit.

But since your maze is made in a silly way

> All glass panels and ceiling are not glued or bolted together meaning you can easily create a cascading dominos effect with a single push on one of the mirror.

your vampire can simply crash down mirrors in a straight line until the far end and then swiping left (or right) until they find the exit.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150833/discussion-on-answer-by-l-dutch-how-can-a-vampire-navigates-a-mirror-maze); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.